# Why doesnt Acrobat Distiller embed all fonts fully?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat, font-embedding

When I use Acrobat Distiller (v.9.1.3), it seems that I cannot embed all fonts -- at least not in the way I want to (no subsetting). One example is Wingdings (TrueType).

I activated the tickboxes and settings to *"Always embed"* and *"No subsetting"*. If I check in a text editor the `*.joboptions` file that I saved as my custom Distiller profile it clearly says:

```
/EmbedAllFonts true
/EmbedOpenType true
/MaxSubsetPct 1
/SubsetFonts false
```

Some fonts Distiller does embed fully (as requested by me), others not. If I change the setting to do font subsetting, this works with ***all*** fonts. Therefore I think that my settings are correct.

Does anyone else experience the same problem/bug with Acrobat?

Comment: subsetting is always done with these font formats primarily because of file size. CID fonts contain the entire Unicode character space which is 1000s of glyphs, most of which a document will never use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.  ;-)

It so happens that yesterday I was wondering about the very same problem. I then resorted to the official PDF specification as published by Adobe. And there ([adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFCreationSettings_v9.pdf#page=36](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFCreationSettings_v9.pdf#page=36)) I read:

---

*"The following table identifies the types of fonts that you can (or cannot) embed or subset through Distiller settings.*

#### Distiller control over embedding and subsetting fonts:

```
 ================== ==================== ============= =====================
 Font?              NeverEmbed?          AlwaysEmbed?  Subset?           
 ================== ==================== ============= =====================
 Type1              Yes                  Yes           Yes                  
 Type3              No (always embedded) -             No (always subsetted)
 TrueType (Type42)  Yes                  Yes           No (always subsetted)
 CIDFontType0       Yes                  Yes           No (always subsetted)
 CIDFontType1       No (always embedded) -             No (always subsetted)
 CIDFontType2       Yes                  Yes           No (always subsetted)
 OpenType           Yes                  Yes           Yes
```

*For additional information on Type 1, Type 3, Type 42, and CID-keyed fonts, see Chapter 5, “Fonts,” in the PostScript Language Reference and Chapter 5 in the PDF Reference. You also can find additional documentation on fonts 
at the [Acrobat Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/go/acrobat_developer/).*
"**Note:** *Distiller 5 and above also support OpenType fonts; Distiller 4 does not. OpenType fonts are based on the compact font format (CFF). For more information, see the Compact Font Format Specification at the
 [Acrobat Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/go/acrobat_developer/)."*

---

#### So this explains it all:

According to the official Adobe specification...

- ***...Type3 and CIDFontType1 are always embedded, even if you set a fontname which happens to be
    one of these 2 fonttypes to*** **"Don't embed"** ***;***
- ***...Type3, TrueType (Type42), CIDFontType0, CIDFontType1 and CIDFontType2 are always subset, 
    even if you set a fontname which happens to be one of these 5 fonttype to*** **"Don't subset"**.

Comment: Of course, one can argue that nevertheless it's a **bug in Adobe's user documentation** if one can only find such info in the *developer* documents...