# Optimize PDF files (with Ghostscript or other)

Tags: linux, pdf, debian, ghostscript

Is Ghostscript the best option if you want to optimize a PDF file and reduce the file size?

I need to store alot of PDF files and therefore I need to optimize and reduce the file size as much as possible

Does anyone have any experience with Ghostscript and/or other?

## command line

```
exec('gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -sOutputFile='.$file_new.' '.$file);
```

Comment: Are you looking for gratis or Free Software only? Or is proprietary pay-ware also an option?

Comment: Have you got any idea which objects in your PDFs are using the most space? Fonts? Hi-res images?

Comment: See also the pdfsizeopt tool (GPLv2) https://askubuntu.com/a/1011292/19753

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you looking for a Free (as in 'libre') Software, Ghostscript is surely your best choice. However, it is not always easy to use -- some of its (very powerful) processing options are not easy to find documented.

Have a look at this answer, which explains how to execute a more detailed control over image resolution downsampling than what the generic `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` does (that defines a few overall defaults, which you may want to override):

- [**How to downsample images within pdf file?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571488/359307)

Basically, it tells you how to make Ghostscript downsample all images to a resolution of 72dpi (this value is what `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` uses -- you may want to go even lower):

```
-dDownsampleColorImages=true \
-dDownsampleGrayImages=true \
-dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
-dColorImageResolution=72 \
-dGrayImageResolution=72 \
-dMonoImageResolution=72 \
```

If you want to try if Ghostscript is able to also 'un-embed' the fonts used (sometimes it works, sometimes not -- depending on the complexity of the embedded font, and also [**on the font type used**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489369/359307)), you can try to add the following to your gs command:

```
gs \
  -o output.pdf \
   [...other options...] \
  -dEmbedAllFonts=false \
  -dSubsetFonts=true \
  -dConvertCMYKImagesToRGB=true \
  -dCompressFonts=true \
  -c ".setpdfwrite <</AlwaysEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams" \
  -c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [/Courier /Courier-Bold /Courier-Oblique /Courier-BoldOblique /Helvetica /Helvetica-Bold /Helvetica-Oblique /Helvetica-BoldOblique /Times-Roman /Times-Bold /Times-Italic /Times-BoldItalic /Symbol /ZapfDingbats /Arial]>> setdistillerparams" \
  -f input.pdf
```

**Note:** Be aware that downsampling image resolution will surely reduce quality (irreversibly), and dis-embedding fonts will make it difficult or impossible to display and print the PDFs unless the same fonts are installed on the machine....

---

### Update

One option which I had overlooked in my original answer is to add

```
-dDetectDuplicateImages=true
```

to the command line. This parameter leads Ghostscript to try and detect any images which are embedded in the PDF multiple times. This can happen if you use an image as a logo or page background, and if the PDF-generating software is not optimized for this situation. This used to be the case with older versions of OpenOffice/LibreOffice (I tested the latest release of LibreOffice, v4.3.5.2, and it does no longer do such stupid things).

It also happens if you concatenate PDF files with the help of `pdftk`. To show you the effect, and how you can discover it, let's look at a sample PDF file:

```
pdfinfo p1.pdf

 Producer:       libtiff / tiff2pdf - 20120922
 CreationDate:   Tue Jan  6 19:36:34 2015
 ModDate:        Tue Jan  6 19:36:34 2015
 Tagged:         no
 UserProperties: no
 Suspects:       no
 Form:           none
 JavaScript:     no
 Pages:          1
 Encrypted:      no
 Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
 Page rot:       0
 File size:      20983 bytes
 Optimized:      no
 PDF version:    1.1
```

Recent versions of Poppler's `pdfimages` utility have added support for a `-list` parameter, which can list all images included in a PDF file:

```
pdfimages -list p1.pdf

 page num  type width height color comp bpc  enc interp objectID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   0 image    423   600   rgb    3   8 jpeg     no     7  0    52    52 19.2K 2.6%
```

This sample PDF is a 1-page document, containing an image, which is compressed with JPEG-compression, has a width of 423 pixels and a height of 600 pixels and renders at a resolution of 52 PPI on the page.

If we concatenate 3 copies of this file with the help of `pdftk` like so:

```
pdftk p1.pdf p1.pdf p1.pdf cat output p3.pdf
```

then the result shows these image properties via `pdfimages -list`:

```
pdfimages -list p3.pdf

 page num  type width height color comp bpc  enc interp objectID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   0 image   423    600   rgb    3   8 jpeg     no     4  0    52    52 19.2K 2.6%
    2   1 image   423    600   rgb    3   8 jpeg     no     8  0    52    52 19.2K 2.6%
    3   2 image   423    600   rgb    3   8 jpeg     no    12  0    52    52 19.2K 2.6%
```

This shows that there are 3 identical PDF objects (with the IDs 4, 8 and 12) which are embedded in `p3.pdf` now. `p3.pdf` consists of 3 pages:

```
pdfinfo p3.pdf | grep Pages:

 Pages:          3
```

#### Optimize PDF by replacing duplicate images with references

Now we can apply the above mentioned optimization with the help of Ghostscript

```
 gs -o p3-optim.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDetectDuplicateImages=true p3.pdf
```

Checking:

```
 pdfimages -list p3-optim.pdf

 page num  type width height color comp bpc  enc interp objectID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   0 image   423    600   rgb    3   8 jpeg     no    10  0    52    52 19.2K 2.6%
    2   1 image   423    600   rgb    3   8 jpeg     no    10  0    52    52 19.2K 2.6%
    3   2 image   423    600   rgb    3   8 jpeg     no    10  0    52    52 19.2K 2.6%
```

There is still one image listed per page -- but the PDF object ID is always the same now: 10.

```
 ls -ltrh p1.pdf p3.pdf p3-optim.pdf

   -rw-r--r--@ 1 kp  staff    20K Jan  6 19:36 p1.pdf
   -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff    60K Jan  6 19:37 p3.pdf
   -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff    16K Jan  6 19:40 p3-optim.pdf
```

As you can see, the "dumb" concatentation made with pdftk increased the original file size to three times the original one. The optimization by Ghostscript brought it down by a considerable amount.

The most recent versions of Ghostscript may even apply the `-dDetectDuplicateImages` by default. *(AFAIR, v9.02, which introduced it for the first time, didn't use it by default.)*

Comment: thanks for the answer :) have tested it, but when you set the dpi to `72` manually the quality is lower when the setting `/screen` is set and the file size is still lower with `/screen` :)

Comment: what I meant was.. The quality is both better with `/screen` and the file size is lower compard to manually setting the dpi to `72`

Comment: @clarkk: I'd be interested to see a sample PDF which shows this happening. Can you provide one (or is this invading someone's privacy)?

Comment: here http://www.dynaccount.com/tmp/35.pdf and here http://www.dynaccount.com/tmp/36.pdf.. Look at the logo in the top of the document.. 35.pdf (44.81kb - manually dpi) and 36.pdf (44.73kb - /screen)

Comment: @clarkk: To make sure I do understand -- these two files are the results of the two conversion commands? (I was interested in one of your original PDFs so I could play with the conversion parameters myself....)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, a list of options that can be used for converting PDFs with GhostScript/ps2pdf is available here: http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm

Answer (score 37):

You can obtain good results by converting from PDF to Postscript, then back to PDF using

```
pdf2ps file.pdf file.ps
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook file.ps file-optimized.pdf
```

The value of argument `-dPDFSETTINGS` defines the quality of the images in the resulting PDF. Options are, from low to high quality: `/screen`, `/default`, `/ebook`, `/printer`, `/prepress`, see http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/ for a reference.

The Postscript file can become quite large, but the results are worth it. I went from a 60 MB PDF to a 140 MB Postscript file, but ended up with a 1.1 MB optimized PDF.

Comment: It would be awesome to get some help with how to do this in a Windows environment...

Comment: Any reason why this would result in smaller files than just using `gs` with suitable settings? In addition, doing this will result in some issues caused by Postscript missing some features (e.g. alpha transparency, gradients, ICC profiles).

Comment: I don't know, just reporting what worked well in my case hoping that others might also benefit from it. Feel free to post a better solution or help improving the existing ones.

Comment: The first step is unnecessary. ps2pdf will accept pdf input files.

Comment: @frabjous Converting to ps first makes a huge difference for me. This is with version 9.26 of ps2pdf and pdf2ps

Comment: @ariddell For me using ps2pdf directly resulted in the smaller file. So it seems it might be worth to try both (or understand the rule behind it).

Answer (score 10):

I use Ghostscript with following options taken from [here](http://blog.rot13.org/2011/05/optimize-pdf-file-size-using-ghostscript.html).

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: Please note that while this one usually works fine it will fail to properly work with fillable PDFs

Comment: @AlexFlo what command would u use to achieve this? I am stuck now because of this.

Answer (score 7):

You may find that `pdftocairo` (from [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)) can make smaller PDFs but beware that it will strip some features (such as hyperlinks) away.

Comment: Thanks, I found that ps2pdf14 sometimes changes the output, and in this case, pdftocairo made the PDF smaller (500K to 110K) but cropped, so I added explicit margin in Inkscape before saving as PDF, **then** ran it through `pdftocairo` and **then** through `pdfcrop` (from Teχ) shrinking it to 90K.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

Convert your PDF to PS (this creates a large file

```
pdf2ps large.pdf very_large.ps
```

Convert the new PS back to a PDF

```
ps2pdf very_large.ps small.pdf
```

Source:
https://pandemoniumillusion.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/compress-a-pdf-with-pdftk/

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript comes with `ps2pdf14` utility which can be used to optimise PDF file(s) but on some occasions size of "optimised" file may be bigger than original.

Comment: `ps2pdf14 input.pdf output.pdf` did the same as `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen 
-dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf`. For pure text content the ouput.pdf is 25% of the size the input.file

Comment: `pdfopt` produced bigger output

Comment: pdfopt no longer comes with ghostscript

Answer (score 2):

You will lose in quality but if it's not an issue then ImageMagick's `convert` may proves helpful :

```
convert original.pdf reduced.pdf
```

Note that it doesn't always work : I once converted a 126 MB file into a 14 MB one using this command, but another time it doubled the size of a 350 Ko file.

Anyway it's worth giving it a try…

As mentioned in comments, of course there is no point in applying this command on a vector-based PDF, it will only be useful on rasterized images.

See also [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/469255/136964) for related options.

Comment: This only make sense for PDF files based on scanned images, otherwise ImageMagick will convert your vector-based PDF into a raster image, and the resulting file might actually be bigger that the original.

Comment: @yms : I guess you're right about vector-based PDFs of course, but I believe it does make sense for any kind of raster images, of which scanned images are only a small subset.  In my case the document was made from plain digital photographs.

Comment: Yes, of course, I meant scanned images as the most common use-case of PDF files with just raster images (and maybe some transparent text from OCR) inside. I just wanted to add that comment as a remark for anyone wanting to use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the PDF which size is mainly due to embedded images (`pdfimages -list` is your friend), typically scanned documents, I would recommend the use of [ocrmypdf](https://github.com/ocrmypdf/OCRmyPDF) which is quite good at [optimizing](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimizer.html), with optional OCR layer as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, that really creates small PDF files using Ghostscript 9.54.0. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76583026/1856757