# PDF optimization for better rendering

Tags: pdf, rendering, preflight

I am looking for PDF optimization techniques/pre-processing to convert Print ready PDF to media ready(Press PDF to web PDF).

Target devices for rendering the PDF are iOS and Android

Tools like Adobe Acrobat Pro, provides settings for such tasks like reduction of layers, merging of layers etc.
Expected output PDF shall have only three layers:
1) Text
2) Image
3) Special effects

We can do this by using pre-flight and thus selecting the layers and merge them.
Any steps to do this effectively, i don't want to do such optimization at page level manually.

Can i import layer (say multiple image.tiff) at multiple pages at a single run?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com)** for that.

If you want to do that via Ghostscript User interface, you can download **[Ghostscript Studio (IDE)](http://ghostscriptstudio.codeplex.com)** and use this switches in the Ghostscript Processor:

```
! >> interaction-related parameters
-dBATCH         ! keep gs out from going into interactive loop reading
-dNOPAUSE       ! disables the prompt and pause at the end of each page

! >> device selection parameters
-sDEVICE = pdfwrite     ! pdf device
-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook
```

Also, take a look at this answer: [Optimize PDF files (with Ghostscript or other)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450120/optimize-pdf-files-with-ghostscript-or-other)

Comment: I am not able to install the IDE, i don't know what problem is.
It says installation was successfull but it doesn't launch...
OS-Win7, 32- bit machine...